# how to match two images and find out mistakes 

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have a template of a letter and many of it's variations (see below) which i acquire from a digital pen :

**Template**

[image: Template]

**Test 1**

[image: Test]

**Test 2**

[image]

These letters are scaled to be in the same bounding box .

I want to detect the mistakes in the letter , like the mistake in Test 1 is that that there is a extra line , and mistake in Test 2 is that there is a missing segment . Similarly there can be a mistake in which there is a curve instead of a line segment . I want to find the parts which need to be corrected . How should i go about doing it ?

Comment: I think this is too broad a computer vision / machine learning problem, rather than a specific programming question. I would be surprised if hand-coded methods would work well here.

Comment: i know it's a computer vision problem , i asked it in opencv forums too , but there are lot less people there . So i thought i should ask here .

Answer (score 2):

One ambiguity is that whether you only want to know the difference between your template and test image or you want to detect letter A by using your template.

As mentioned by you, the difference between your template and test image is of that extra line but i think there are more differences e.g template A is not made of straight lines rather including some curves as well but the test 1 image is approximately made up of straight lines.
These two are different problems in image processing and must be entertained differently. First you have to think what you want to do?

However, one solution is that You can divide the template and test image in sub blocks and try to find the correlation between them, if that gives matching upto a predefined threshold( you should define it intelligently) than there is no difference otherwise mark that block as difference between the template and test image.

Comment: The curve and straight line is because of the error produced when acquiring the data ,  i don't count them as mistake .

Comment: Is there any documentation which explains how to find correlation and what is correlation wrt images.

Comment: I dnt know about OPENCV but you can check following links,www.vast.uccs.edu/~tboult/CS330/NOTES/OpenCVTutorial_III.ppt,http://signal.ee.psu.edu/2011.2.4%20OpenCV%20Tutorial%20I.pdf

Answer (score 0):

you can use xcorr2 function in MATLAB and MATLAB help is sufficient to understand the working of this function.

Comment: Is there similar function in Opencv ?

Comment: @rajat there is a similar function in `scipy` and `numpy`